# How long do photos inserted into a google document last, after the google document is deleted?

Tags: html, image, google-docs, google-docs-api

I noticed that Google Docs has an option both [programatically](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate#InsertInlineImageRequest) and manually, to insert an image to the inline document.

Then, when you export it as an HTML page (googledocURlExceptForTheEditPartAtTheEnd!/export?format=html ) the images inserted are embedded into that HTML page wit ha source URL to some google content link.

The question: say I publish that HTML page somewhere, then do I have to keep that google doc eternally in my google drive in order for those pictures to work still? Do they ever expire once the source document is deleted?

Comment: If the image source url is deleted, then html will obviously not show the image, but text will remain. However, if there's a base64 encoded image datauris, it will not expire

Comment: @TheMaster that is my exact question though, when you export it it creates a content (not base64) url, somehow linked to google photos I think, like content.google.com/somereallylongurl or something like that, but the question is is that link deactivated after I delete the google doc that the image was originally inserted into? I heard a deleted image's URL is removed after 60 days, but would the same apply to an image inserted in the actual document itself?

Comment: I believe so, but why don't you try and see?  When I tested Google photos, the link expired at about 4-7 days. I haven't tested Google docs, but I expect it also to expire in a similar fashion

Comment: Interesting, OK cool so I should keep the doc I guess then